# Why am I not getting the correct size after using malloc and printing using sizeof?

Tags: c

This is my code.

```
#include<stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    int a,b;
    } integers;

void main() {
    integers *ptr = (integers *)malloc(10*sizeof(integers));
    printf("%d",sizeof(*ptr)); // prints 8

}
```

From what I understand about Malloc, the above code should actually reserve 10x8=80 bytes of memory for ptr to point to.

Why then does using sizeof(*ptr) give only 8? How do I find the total size being allocated for ptr?

Comment: because sizeof is compile time construct, not runtime, also `*ptr` means `ptr[0]` which is 8 bytes :)

Comment: The total size being allocated for `ptr` is the size you requested, which you know to be `10*sizeof(integers)` unless `malloc()` returns `NULL` which you should always check for.

Comment: Yes but right now, that ptr does not point to anything in particular. So, is there any way to find out how much of the allocated memory I am using?

Comment: There is no need to typecast the returned pointer from malloc in C.

Comment: The syntax says `sizeof expr` (or `sizeof (type)` ) Just look at the source, and find out what the *size* of your *expression* is. BTW: `main()` should return int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I know that this question is pretty outdated but finding no suitable answer, I decided to write one.
When specifying `sizeof(*ptr)`, you're actually trying to reach out for the size of data type you've stored in the variable that the pointer is pointing to( here its the first element of the array). Here, that's quite evidently 8.

Even when you'll try to print `sizeof(ptr)`, you'll be again printing the size of the **pointer address** which by default is 8 bytes in GCC compilers as the data type is long unsigned int.

Answer (score 2):

Because you're using `sizeof(*ptr)` you're actually asking for the size of the first element in the allocated buffer, thus `sizeof` will return the size of the **first element in `ptr`** (i.e. 2x4 bytes integers on 32bits system) rather than the allocated size.

Also, please note that even if you'd use `sizeof(ptr)` you'd get the size of the `ptr` pointer which on 32bits system would be 4 bytes.

Comment: Actually, if I use sizeof(ptr), I get the output to be 4.

Comment: @AdarshRao:  __Part 1:__ The value of `sizeof(*ptr)` is the size of a single object of type `integers`. If I can assume that your `int` is a 32 bit integer, then `integers` will have a size of `8`.  __Part 2:__ The value of `sizeof(ptr)` is the size of a pointer. This will usually be 4 or 8 bytes depending on your platform.

Comment: This is because you're compiling your code with 32 bits architecture where a pointer is 32 bits (4 bytes) long.

Answer (score 1):

> Why then does using sizeof(*ptr) give only 8? How do I find the total size being allocated for ptr?

The type of the expression `*ptr` is `integers` - thus,

```
sizeof *ptr == sizeof (integers) == sizeof (int) + sizeof (int)
```

You cannot determine the size of the allocated buffer by looking at the pointer (it doesn't store any metadata about the buffer size).  You will have to keep track of that information separately.

**Edit**

Note that you can do something like the following:

```
 integers (*foo)[10] = malloc( sizeof *foo );
 if ( foo )
   printf( "sizeof *foo = %zu\n", sizeof *foo );
```

and that will give you the result you're expecting.  In this case, `foo` is a pointer to an *array* of `integers`, not to a single instance of `integers`, so `sizeof *foo` will give you the size of the allocated array.  The downside is that you have to expliticly dereference `foo` before applying the subscript:

```
(*foo)[i].a = some_value();         // or foo[0][i].a
(*foo)[i].b = some_other_value();   // or foo[0][i].b
```

This is normally done when you want to allocate an NxM array and make sure all the rows are contiguous:

```
integers (*foo)[10] = malloc( 10 * sizeof *foo );
```

will allocate a 10x10 array of `integers` such that the rows are all adjacent in memory.

Also, a pointer to a 10-element array of `integers` is not compatible with a pointer to an 11-element array of `integers`, making it more difficult to write functions that can work with pointers to arrays of different sizes.  IOW, if you have a function declared as

```
void bar( integers (*foo)[10] ) { ... }
```

it can *only* work with Nx10 arrays of `integers`.  There are ways around this that involve varying levels of pain, but that's a topic for another day.